# Get consumer lag programmatically with broker based offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, metrics

I have been combing through the internet, literally, for a whole day and couldnt fine one working example.

All I want is the consumer group lag metric (Or the 2 offsets its derived from, current and last), for a given groupID.

Im using kafka 0.9+ (So no offsets in zookeeper) and can also use newer ones if needed.

I need a way to get it **programmatically, not using the scripts.**

Someone, please, how do I get it?????

Comment: You mean like from inside a consumer's poll loop? Or what?

Comment: If so, sorry to suggest things you've already tried but shouldn't some combination of `consumer.subscribe()` followed by `consumer.position()` and `consumer.endOffsets()` work?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, what you suggested maybe work but I dont want to have to query each consumer individually, I want to get the info for a group, which shouldnt be a problem since its there... Kafka guys really dropped the ball on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Work is currently underway to add a way to retrieve consumer group details via the AdminClient, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=74686265.

In the meantime, your best option is reuse the logic from the `kafka-consumer-group` tool. It is backed by this Scala class: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala and it should not be very hard to extract the bit that retrieves the details for all instances in a group.

Comment: I tried, couldnt understand this class or import it to my env and get it running...

Comment: So I tried this but what I found was that if you have a cluster with lots of consumers...it takes a long time to run and occupies a ton of resources on the broker....it doesn't seem to scale very well if you want to programmatically pull all lags every 30seconds

Comment: Note that consumers also emit lag metrics, http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#new_consumer_fetch_monitoring. Depending on what we actually want to do, you could also query each instance through JMX or use a custom metric reporter to send values to another system.